# Найти select по селектору

Tags: jquery

Есть такая разметка:

```
<div class="product-item">
    <a href="#" class="product-item-img-wrap">
    <img src="фото" alt="item"/>
    </a>
    <div class="item-eq-height item-info">
        <div class="product-name">
            <h5 class="product-item-header" style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold;">
                Наименование
            </h5>
        </div>
        <div class="product-item-size" style="font-size: 14px;">
        Размер и артикуль:<br /><br />
        <select style="width: 224px;" name="size">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="product-item-price">
            Цена 
        </div>
        <div class="btn-wrap prod-buy-button">
            <span class="btn-solid btn-add-cart" onclick="addCart(this);" style="cursor: pointer;">Купить</span>
            <input type="hidden" value="<?=$produсt->id?>" name="id"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

В этом блоке есть `<select name="size">`. Как получить к нему доступ по нажатию кнопки "Купить"?

Делаю так, но не работает:

```
function addCart(btn) {
    $this = $(btn);
    var id = $this.siblings('input[name=id]').val();
    var size = $this.closest('.product_list').find('select[name="size"]').val();
    alert(size);
}
```

Comment: не вижу элемента с классом *product_list*

Comment: У вас нет в разметке класса product_list, к которому вы обращаетесь в обработчике.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, я невнимательно посмотрел, но не могу в вашей разметке найти `product_list`, который используется в `closest('.product_list')`.
Может быть, там `product-item` должен быть?

Comment: блин(((( ошибся, спасибо заработало